# php foreach loop not working on other (language) pages

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

On my multilanguage website a have a foreach loop that's implemented on 4 pages.
On the english homepage & casestudie page and the dutch homepage & projecten page.
It is working fine on the english homepage & casestudie page but it's not working on the dutch homepage & projecten page.

When I test if it is an array then it is on the english pages an array but not on the dutch pages.

This error started suddenly in december 2020 before that it is was fine.

Example to see https://nitesco.swtest.nl/ at **Selected clients** there are logos, those are generated by the foreachloop and https://nitesco.swtest.nl/nl/ at **Selectie van onze klanten** there are no logo's

I hope somebody can help me to get it work again.

The code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <hr class="section__divider">
    <section class="section">
        <h4 class="section__title"><?php echo trans('Selected clients', 'Selectie van onze klanten') ?></h4>
        <ul class="clients-logos">
        <?php 
       $selected_clients = get_field('selected_clients', 'option');
        if (is_array($selected_clients) || is_object($selected_clients))
        {
            foreach ($selected_clients as $client) { ?>
                <li><img src="<?=$client['url']?>" alt="<?=$client['alt']?>"></li>
            <?php
                
            } ?>  
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: _“When I test if it is an array then it is on the english pages an array but not on the dutch pages.”_ - so go and check what the option field you are reading there actually contains then.

Comment: Try adding var_dump($selected_clients); before the if statement, and see what is actually being returned.

Comment: Do other 'Option' fields get brought through o.k. on the Dutch pages?

Comment: Whenever you have an `if`, always include an `else` unless you don't care if it doesn't run. That's where you can often put some debugging code.

Comment: I have added var_dump($selected_clients); and on the enlish homepage there is returning a lot see 
---
array(25) { [0]=> array(24) { ["ID"]=> int(393) ["id"]=> int(393) ["title"]=> string(8) "COLLIERS" ["filename"]=> string(14) "COLLIERS-2.jpg" ["filesize"]=> int(2226) ["url"]=> string(67) "https://nitesco.swtest.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/COLLIERS-2.jpg" ["link"]=> string(37) "https://nitesco.swtest.nl/colliers-3/" ["alt"]=> string(0) ""
enz....
-------
And onthe dutch home it's returning: bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code but is did not help:

```
$page = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $page.'<br><br>';    

?>
    <div class="container">
        <hr class="section__divider">
        <section class="section">
            <h4 class="section__title"><?php echo trans('Selected clients', 'Selectie van onze klanten') ?></h4>
            <ul class="clients-logos">
            <?php
            
                if (strpos($page, '/nl/') !== false) {
                    echo 'true'.'<br><br>';
                }
            if(strpos($page, '/nl/') !== false) {
                    $logo_klanten = get_field('selected_clients_nl', 'option');
                     if (is_array($logo_klanten)){
                        echo 'dit is een array <br>';
                        
                    }else{
                         
                        echo 'dit is geen array!<br>'; 
                     }
                        
                    echo "VAR_DUMP(logo_klanten) <br>";
                    var_dump($logo_klanten);
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<br>";
                    foreach ($logo_klanten as $klant) { ?>
            
                        <li><img src="<?=$klant['url']?>" alt="<?=$klant['alt']?>"></li>
                
            <?php 
                    }
                    unset($klant);
                
            }else{
                    $logo_clients = get_field('selected_clients', 'option');
                    if (is_array($logo_clients)){
                        echo 'dit is een array <br>';
                        
                    }else{
                         
                        echo 'dit is geen array!<br>'; 
                     }
                        
                    echo "VAR_DUMP(logo_clients) <br>";
                    var_dump($logo_clients);
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<br>";
                    if (is_array($logo_clients)){
                        foreach ($logo_clients as $client) { ?>
                
                            <li><img src="<?=$client['url']?>" alt="<?=$client['alt']?>"></li>
                    
                        <?php 
                    
                        }
                    }
                unset($client);
            }
            
            
            
            
            ?>                
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
```

You can see it: https://nitesco.swtest.nl/nl/
It should be an array.